# Missing the User Settings button in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, button, azure-devops, azure-functions

Missing the User Settings button.  Does anyone know how to get this to appear?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure DevOps Service, you could find the User Settings button left beside your profile:

[image]

In Azure DevOps Server, you could click your profile from upper right corner to find the User Setting page:

[image]